# How to handle text with dragable tags in it?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, desktop-application

I need to have a textbox (sort of) where the user can enter text and drop "tags" in ir from a list.

So, for example you can end having:  "This is a <<**dragable tag**>> and this is not."

What I need to achieve is that the tag, being part of the text, shouldn't be modified, just deleted. The tag should have a certain styling like a green pill or something (like Gmail labels for instance).  I mean, I can implement the text conversin of what the user droped into the textbox, but this can then be modified.

This is a WinForms application in .NET 2.0 or higher.

**EDIT: Adding an image to further explain this:**
[image]

The problem I'm facing is that the "Diagnosis" textbox  should handle text and the droped green labels.  Obviously this is not a normal textbox... so I can imagine how to handle user text input and the labels.  I have seen this in some expression editors over there where once the label is placed you cannot edit its text just deleting it (it behaves like a single character).

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** If you know about this for ASP.NET MVC is also appreciated as a WebUI is closer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the web part you could use several javascript-libraries to archive the drag-drop part.
For example, for JQueryUI, look at this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#shopping-cart.

Have fun with WinForms :P